# SQL Server 2008 debugger

Tags: debugging, sql-server-2008

Using the SQL Server 2008 debugger, how can I see the contents of a local table-valued variable in a stored procedure? In the locals window its value is listed as "(table)", but I can't see the contents. I saw some references to an "Immediate" window at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2008/64354/ (note registration required to see this article) but I couldn't find how to open it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you register in that site you can see the article . 
If you register only you can see :)

Hope below diagram  will help you

[alt text http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/8548/20928548.jpg](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/8548/20928548.jpg)

[alt text http://img129.imageshack.us/img129/2998/57154571.jpg](http://img129.imageshack.us/img129/2998/57154571.jpg)

[alt text http://img129.imageshack.us/img129/935/74405379.jpg](http://img129.imageshack.us/img129/935/74405379.jpg)

[alt text http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/4213/98916248.jpg](http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/4213/98916248.jpg)

You can debug same as visual studio.

[alt text http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/9083/48169595.jpg](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/9083/48169595.jpg)

Read this one too

https://web.archive.org/web/20210510024057/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051607-1.aspx

Comment: Sorry didn't realise it was register required, I have a cookie on that site. Thanks for the info, but you didn't answer the specific question: how do I get the value of a table variable when debugging a stored procedure. I can do all the bit that you've said so far (albeit in SSMS 2008, your article relates to SQL Server 2005, which is quite different).

Comment: what you mean by value of table variable ? all the values in a particular column of a table ?

Comment: I want to see what I would see if I type "select * from @tablevariable"